# Is there a civi way to manage API compatibility across CiviCRM versions?

Tags: extension

Working on an extension that is aiming to be compatible with 4.6 and 4.7. The complete PCP api is only available as of 4.7 as far as I can tell.

So for 4.6 users, the extension can include the PCP api but "bypassed" for 4.7 users?

Because the api implementation in the extension is in api/*/*. So how can 4.7 ignore this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call an API, Civi does a search to locate it. That typically means searching the PHP `include_path` for a file named `api/v3/{$entity}/{$action}.php` or `api/v3/{$entity}.php`. The `include_path` is typically managed via `hook_civicrm_config`.

It sounds like want to change `hook_civicrm_config` so that the effect is:

- Add `/path/to/org.example.myext/` to the `include_path` unconditionally. This contains all you're normal/common files.
- Add `/path/to/org.example.myext/backports` to the `include_path` if it's an old version (4.6). This contains only the backports/polyfills for older versions.

In most `civix`-based extensions, it does the first automatically with this snippet:

```
function {myext}_civicrm_config(&$config) {
  _{myext}_civix_civicrm_config($config);
}
```

The `_{myext}_civix_civicrm_config()` is a baseline/default implementation that unconditionally adds `/path/to/org.example.myext/` to the `include_path`. Take a look at the code in `_{myext}_civix_civicrm_config($config)` to see how it works.

Then you can write a similar function to add `/path/to/org.example.myext/backports`. Finally, call it:

```
function {myext}_civicrm_config(&$config) {
  _{myext}_civix_civicrm_config($config)
  if (version_compare(CRM_Utils_System::version(), '4.7', '<')) {
    _{myext}_config_backports($config);
  }
}

function _{myext}_config_backports(&$config) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the civicrm setting API to check which version you are working with?

```
$version = civicrm_api3('Domain', 'getvalue', array('return' => "version"));
```